# Getting socket hangup error when using mailchimp api in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, api

i am trying to send a list containing info from a form to mailchimp server,it requires a basic http authentication. When i am sending the request using curl i am able to retrieve the page, but when i run the local sever it is showing socket errors.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static("public/"));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/signup.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  const fn = req.body.fn;
  const sn = req.body.ln;
  const mail = req.body.mailid;
  const data ={
    members: [
      {
      email_address: mail,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME : fn,
        LNAME :sn
      }
    }
  ]
};
var url = "https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/*listid*";
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
var options ={
  method: "POST",
  auth:"*username*:*key*"
};
const request = https.request(url,options,function(response){
response.on("d",function(d){
  console.log(JSON.parse(d));

});


request.write(jsonData);
request.end();
});
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("at 3000");
});
```

i am getting the following 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aav7K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```js
response.on("d",function(d){
  console.log(JSON.parse(d));
});
```

to

```js
response.on("data",function(d){
  console.log(JSON.parse(d));
});
```

and make sure to end the request by specifying `request.end();`. Otherwise it will not stop posting to the server you have to end posting.